# How to get auto increment number if database is empty?

Tags: android, sqlite

In the app I am building I have a auto increment row, so say i add 3 entries to the sql database in android it be 0,1,2 but say i delete the 3 entries from the database and then add another it will continue auto increment number from the last auto increment number that was put in the database, so if i delete all entries in the database how do i get the last auto increment number if there is Notting left in the database at the time?

### Update

When trying to use "SELECT last_insert_rowid()" i get a load of rubbish:

in database file i have:

```
 public Cursor getmax(){
        return databaseConnect.rawQuery("SELECT last_insert_rowid()", null);
    }
```

and in the file im trying to get last row if back:

```
  Cursor reminder = databaseHelper.getmax();
 String title = reminder + "";
```

i need to covert to string like above but when i check it i get a load of rubbish back ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's android I'm guessing it's SQLLite, and you should be able to use

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid()
```

Comment: could you read the update on the post ... i keep getting rubbish values back ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always get the max of a column and add one to it

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
String maxValue = "0";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT seq FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE sqlite_sequence.name = 'MY_TABLE'", null);
if (c != null && c.moveToFirst())
    maxValue = String.valueOf(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("seq")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

-Createa a [Database trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) for inserts, such that an insert operation returns the ID of the row it just inserted.  Store that value somewhere like a shared preference.

-The auto-incrementing index shouldn't start over just because the database is empty.  If you want the index of the last row, just insert a row, check its index, and subtract one.  Then delete the empty row (update your "last inserted index" accordingly)